# Comparação com dados gravados como JSON

Tags: postgresql

Tenho um campo de data que é gravado no campo em formato JSON, junto com outros valores

```
{"data_limite":"14\/07\/2016","data_programada":null,"admin_agendamento":"4813"}
```

Esse campo "data limite", preciso, em outra tela, colocar em um CASE-WHEN para verificar se essa data está a 24, 48 ou 72 horas de chegar no dia de hoje.

Essa é a minha dúvida: Como realizar uma comparação em um CASE-WHEN com um dado gravado com outros valores?

**EDIT**:Meu postgres é 8.3, portanto, sem suporte a JSON, é gravado em um campo TEXT

**EDIT 2**: Trecho do SQL que tenho que executar:

```
...
CASE
    WHEN tbl_cliente_admin.nome IS NOT NULL AND tbl_hd_chamado_extra.hd_chamado NOT NULL AND finalizada IS NULL AND array_campos_adicionais NOT NULL AND (AQUI TENHO QUE COMPARAR)::date - CURRENT_DATE >= 3
    THEN 3
    WHEN tbl_cliente_admin.nome IS NOT NULL AND tbl_hd_chamado_extra.hd_chamado NOT NULL AND finalizada IS NULL AND array_campos_adicionais NOT NULL AND (AQUI TENHO QUE COMPARAR)::date - CURRENT_DATE > 1
    THEN 2
    WHEN tbl_cliente_admin.nome IS NOT NULL AND tbl_hd_chamado_extra.hd_chamado NOT NULL AND finalizada IS NULL AND array_campos_adicionais NOT NULL AND (AQUI TENHO QUE COMPARAR)::date - CURRENT_DATE <= 1
    THEN 1
    ELSE 4
END AS termino_atendimento
...
```

Comment: Você precisa fazer essa comparação direto no banco ou está pode ser na aplicação? (PHP, etc..)

Comment: Sim, direto no banco, pois não tenho parâmetros anteriores para buscar antes e fazer na aplicação. Preciso pegar esse "data_limite" e fazer nosso querido e amado INTERVAL 1, 2 ou 3 days.

Comment: Achei esse link talvez ajude: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836025/postgresql-query-between-time-range-using-jsonb-field segundo o link ->> extrai o campo de dentro do JSOn

Comment: Ajudaria @LucasQueirozRibeiro, mas, como disse no meu EDIT, meu banco é 8.2, não tem suporte a JSON. Esse suporte é a partir do 9. Pelas minhas andanças, precisaria fazer um sub-select para procurar por dentro de cada CASE, mas ficaria muito pesado.

Comment: Achei o que precisava: usarei o `split_part()`. Fiz os testes e me atendeu. Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fatorando o seu case:

```
case
    tbl_cliente_admin.nome is not null and
    tbl_hd_chamado_extra.hd_chamado is not null and
    finalizada is null
    when true then
        case split_part(split_part(json, '","', 1), '":"', 2)::date - current_date
            when 0 then 1
            when 1 then 1
            when 2 then 2
            else 3
        end
    else 4
end as termino_atendimento
```

Note que tanto o seu case quanto esta versão fatorada vão retornar 1 para datas anteriores à atual.

Comment: Exatamente o que meu companheiro de trabalho fez aqui.